# Whitelist Multipart file upload in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Please bear with me. I am having an issue allowing files to be uploaded without needing authorization as it is part of a registration process. I have added the path to my upload in the antMatchers.permitAll() but Spring still throws a 401 Unauthorized when I try to do an upload. Can somebody please assist me? I have been struggling with this for a while now.

This is my security config

```
@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
    authenticationManagerBuilder
            .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v0/business-registration", "/api/v0/business-registration/file","/api/v0/admin/register", "/api/v0/admin/login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();

    // Add our custom JWT security filter
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I was missing the /*/** in the antMatchers and my controller has path variables which is why I was getting the 401 error.